# How to use map function to list the array in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, map-function, react-functional-component

Here is my code:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react'

export const ListPage: FunctionComponent = () => {
 const list = [
  {
    title: 'I like React'
  },
  {
    title: 'I also like Angular'
  }
 ]

 const listTag = () => {
  list.map(
    item => {
     <h1>{item.title}</h1>
    }
  )
 }

 return(
  <listTag/>
 )
}
```

But I still get the error message and not able to fetch out the array.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Property 'listTag' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react'

export const ListPage: FunctionComponent = () => {
    const list = [
     {
       title: 'I like React'
     },
     {
       title: 'I also like Angular'
     }
    ];

    const ListTag = () => list.map(item => (<h1>{item.title}</h1>))

    return (
      <ListTag />
    )
}
```

Note: Problem in Your code listed below

```
const listTag = () => { //fist letter of component need to be captial
  list.map( // the value of `list.map()` needed to be return
    item => {
    <h1>{item.title}</h1> // here you are not returning the value to map function.
    }
  )
}

return(
  <listTag/> // If You are using any function component make sure the first letter is also captial.
)
```

Comment: const ListTag = () => list.map((item) => <h1>{item.title}</h1>)
Missing return type on function.
'ListTag' cannot be used as a JSX component.

Here is error message, any idea?

Comment: have you tried wrapping up ` <h1>{item.title}</h1>` as `( <h1>{item.title}</h1>)`

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: can you please put you update blog or share your code with codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-gould-jd7h1?file=/src/App.tsx

plz help to check, thank you Orz

Comment: I had change the code please see https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-grass-5zy9q. Does not have enough experience with typescript in react  so  unable to red line error.

Comment: thumbs up I removed the red line warning.